# Can i read the RAM and CPU usage of other applications-Android

Tags: applications, performance, ram

I want to know whether is it possible to monitor the CPU, RAM, Network and Battery usage of each and every application installed in my device through my application dynamically? Does Android's security policy allow this to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor).

Comment: Yes. To get such elaborate details, does the phone needs to be rooted?

Comment: Yes. This requires root.